# Displaying Google Maps Data Layer in HTML Text Area

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I display Google Maps data layer in an HTML textarea?

I need to be able to save changes users make to a map with drawing tools.

This is what I am doing to accomplish this.

1. Display Google Maps Data Layer in html textarea
2. When user clicks"Save Map" content in textarea will be saved in a
   database so that user can view/edit map at a later time.

I have added the code from an existing JSFiddle. The JSFiddle displays a second map. I would like the second map to just display the GeoJSON data.

JSFiddle:

```
jsfiddle{dot}net/mikestratton/z988k7na/    
function initialize() { 

// Create a simple map.
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByTagName('TD')[0].firstChild, {
    zoom: 9,
    center: {
      lat: 41,
      lng: -81
    },
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });
  // test result
  map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByTagName('TD')[1].firstChild, {
    zoom: map.getZoom(),
    center: map.getCenter()
  });
  map2.bindTo('zoom', map, 'zoom');
  map2.bindTo('center', map, 'center');
  // END test result
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    if (feature.getProperty('radius') && feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {
      return {
        visible: false
      };
    }

    return {

    };
  });\
  // test result
  map2.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    if (feature.getProperty('radius') && feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'Point') {

      new google.maps.Circle({
        map: map2,
        center: feature.getGeometry().get(),
        radius: feature.getProperty('radius')
      });
      return {
        visible: false
      };
    }

    return {

    };
  });
// END test result
  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map.data, 'addfeature', function() {
    var btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.type = 'button';
    btn.value = 'save data layer to test result';
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(btn, 'click', function() {
      map2.data.forEach(function(f) {
        map2.data.remove(f);
      });
      map.getGeoJson(function(geo) {
        console.log(map2.data.addGeoJson(geo));
      });
    });
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(btn);

  });
  var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
    map: map,
    drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
    drawingControl: true,
    drawingControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP,
      drawingModes: [
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,
        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE
      ]
    }
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
    switch (event.type) {
      case google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER:
        map.data.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
          geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point(event.overlay.getPosition())
        }));
        break;
      case google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.RECTANGLE:
        var b = event.overlay.getBounds(),
          p = [b.getSouthWest(), {
            lat: b.getSouthWest().lat(),
            lng: b.getNorthEast().lng()
          }, b.getNorthEast(), {
            lng: b.getSouthWest().lng(),
            lat: b.getNorthEast().lat()
          }]
        map.data.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
          geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([p])
        }));
        break;
      case google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON:
        map.data.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
          geometry: new google.maps.Data.Polygon([event.overlay.getPath().getArray()])
        }));
        break;
      case google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE:
        map.data.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
          geometry: new google.maps.Data.LineString(event.overlay.getPath().getArray())
        }));
        break;
      case google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE:
        map.data.add(new google.maps.Data.Feature({
          properties: {
            radius: event.overlay.getRadius()
          },
          geometry: new google.maps.Data.Point(event.overlay.getCenter())
        }));
        break;
    }

  });


}





google.maps.Map.prototype.getGeoJson = function(callback) {
  var geo = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": []
    },
    fx = function(g, t) {

      var that = [],
        arr,
        f = {
          MultiLineString: 'LineString',
          LineString: 'Point',
          MultiPolygon: 'Polygon',
          Polygon: 'LinearRing',
          LinearRing: 'Point',
          MultiPoint: 'Point'
        };

      switch (t) {
        case 'Point':
          g = (g.get) ? g.get() : g;
          return ([g.lng(), g.lat()]);
          break;
        default:
          arr = g.getArray();
          for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            that.push(fx(arr[i], f[t]));
          }
          if (t == 'LinearRing' &&
            that[0] !== that[that.length - 1]) {
            that.push([that[0][0], that[0][1]]);
          }
          return that;
      }
    };

  this.data.forEach(function(feature) {
    var _feature = {
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {}
    }
    _id = feature.getId(),
      _geometry = feature.getGeometry(),
      _type = _geometry.getType(),
      _coordinates = fx(_geometry, _type);

    _feature.geometry = {
      type: _type,
      coordinates: _coordinates
    };
    if (typeof _id === 'string') {
      _feature.id = _id;
    }

    geo.features.push(_feature);
    feature.forEachProperty(function(v, k) {
      _feature.properties[k] = v;
    });
  });
  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback(geo);
  }
  return geo;
}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: What does your existing code look like?  (Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. Have you tried using the [Data Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data) `.toGeoJson()` method?  Its description is "Exports the features in the collection to a GeoJSON object."

Comment: You answered my question. I need to use the Data Layer .toGeoJson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Data Layer .toGeoJson() method to export the current contents of the Data Layer.

from  [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Data):

> **toGeoJson(callback:function(Object))** | Return Value:  None
>
> Exports the features in the collection to a GeoJSON object.

Comment: Is there a way I can contact you offline?